# $TEXINPUTS and texmaker, LaTeXila

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, texinputs

We have a number of .cls files on a central server, the corresponding directory is set in $TEXINPUTS (on Linux) and pdflatex works just fine.

Now I would like to switch to a graphical environment such als LaTeXila or texmaker, which both do not find the cls files as they seem not to use $TEXINPUTS. I could now follow the general advice to place the cls files into ~/texmf/tex/latex/..., but that would just mean to duplicate and sync them frequently.

Is there any way around that?

Comment: the tex used by your frontend will use TEXINPUTS but you just need to make sure that it is set in the shell that launches the application. It depends on the details of your setup.

Comment: You are right, of course ... I moved $TEXINPUTS from ~/.bashrc to ~/.profile and it works just fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tex used by your frontend will use TEXINPUTS but you just need to make sure that it is set in the shell that launches the application. It depends on the details of your setup.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this is to create a link to the server directory under `~/texmf/tex/latex`¹ with something like

```
cd ~/texmf/tex/latex
ln -s /path/to/server/directory
```

---

1. It's worth noting that the `latex` part of the path is not necessary. LaTeX will search all subdirectories of `~/texmf/tex` for input files.