# texliveonfly preamble.sty not found

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, kpsewhich

I'm trying to use `texliveonfly` to automatically install my dependencies. However, most of the packages I used are located in a `preamble.sty` file which is in the same folder as the `main.tex` file for my whole document. When I run

```
texliveonfly main.tex
```

I get,

```
! LaTeX Error: File `preamble.sty' not found.
```

I've placed a symbolic link in the `TEXMFHOME` because I've read it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71469/texmfhome-setting).
But it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated :) Thank you.

Comment: you say that the file is `preamble.sty` but the error shows `preambUle.sty`

Comment: Ha yeah ! It's copy pasta error ! My file is called preambule.sty (which is French). I forgot to modify the error line ! It is done now, thank you!

Comment: Are you a Ubuntu user?

Comment: Yes mister ! Ubuntu 18.10, texlive 2018 tlmgr latest !

Comment: Not a frequent user of linux but what is the response to `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` note it should end /texmf then your sty files should be in ~/texmf/tex/latex/local/ (which is one expected TDS location) your cls files can also go there and to double up setting $TEXINPUTS= texmf location : including : other folders should help see related questions such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411418/texinputs-and-texmaker-latexila

Comment: First I've tried adding my preamble to the location specified by `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` and the file preamble.sty could still not be found. Then I tried changing `TEXMFHOME` to the folder of my project, still did not work.

Comment: The key is the manager needs to know so tex live manager needs a command such as texhash or similar and in such cases its can be worth to exit and re-enter (logon or reboot) to check if it was / still is registered at start-up ALSO note its not always the texmf folder but the latex/local below it

Comment: Ok, I got it. My document is organized in subfolers like Thesis is the home folder and contains Main, Intro, Chap 1, etc .. And Main countais main.tex and preamble.sty I was running : `texliveonfly Main/main.tex` and got the error. I tried running it from Main folder and it worked ! (`cd Main && texliveonfly main.tex`)

Comment: Topically a good candidate for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480926/what-s-the-end-best-way-to-organise-texstudio-files